# Running MongoDB within a Singularity container

Tags: mongodb, singularity-container

I built a Singularity container with the MongoDB software in it, and wanted to execute it, calling `systemctl start mongod` in the `%runscript` section.
This results in the output

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request: start
```

Are there some additional configurations I need to do in my container setup?
Or in configuring MongoDB?
I'm not familiar in dealing with chroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singularity works by having all processes run inside the container as the user running it. `systemctl` starts a daemon (generally) owned by a service account, which is why it is failing. You'll want to run `mongo` with your desired params / config file directly.

This example repo is a bit dated, but should still work: https://github.com/singularityhub/mongo